# Converting an SQL with Left Join , Group and Sum to a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to replicate the below SQL in C# & Linq , but I am not too experienced with Linq beyond the basics.

```
SELECT SUM(coalesce(cd.minutesspent,0))
FROM timelabels t
LEFT JOIN challengedetails cd on cd.createddate = t.date 
GROUP BY t.date
```

This would give me a sum of minutes for every date, or zero if there were null entries. Pretty straightforward I think.

```
// timelabels structure 
DateTime start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
List<DateTime> timelabels =  new List<DateTime>();
for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    timelabels.Add(dt);
}

// ChallengeDetails structure & sample data
class ChallengeDetails(){
    DateTime? Createddate
    int? MinutesSpent 
}
List<ChallengeDetails> ChallengeDetails = new List<ChallengeDetails >();
  List<ChallengeDetails> ChallengeDetails = new List<ChallengeDetails>();
            ChallengeDetails.Add(new ChallengeDetails { MinutesSpent = 44, Createddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) });
            ChallengeDetails.Add(new ChallengeDetails { MinutesSpent = 31, Createddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) });
            ChallengeDetails.Add(new ChallengeDetails { MinutesSpent = 13, Createddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) });
            ChallengeDetails.Add(new ChallengeDetails { MinutesSpent = 77, Createddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) });


// The Actual Code 
List<string> timedata = (from a in timelabels
                         join al in ChallengeDetails on a equals al.Createddate into All
                         from al in All.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         group al by a into grouped
                         select grouped.Sum(m => m.MinutesSpent ?? 0).ToString()
                        ).ToList();
```

Looking at this it should work - I have  DefaultIfEmpty which should replicate the left join. Within the Sum I have '?? 0' which should be the fallback for any dates that dont have a ChallengeDetail.

But I get System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
m was null.  I shouldnt have gotten this as I have null entries covered or have I got this all wrong  ?

Comment: First, do this with the data layer you're using (which one?). LINQ to object is different than LINQ to a SQL provider. Second thing that probably applies: use navigation properties, not `join`. Doing this the ORM will 1. Cancel null references because it's SQL and 2. Figure out left joins all by itself.

Comment: Try following : select grouped.Sum(m => (m == null) ? 0 :m.MinutesSpent).ToString()

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you. Which LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? Which database provider?

Comment: Sometimes `al` will be `null` in LINQ to Objects (from `DefaultIfEmpty()`) in which case `m` will be `null` and `m.MinutesSpent` will be a `NullReferenceException`. You need `m?.MinutesSpent ?? 0` for LINQ to Objects. This is not the same as LINQ to a database.

Comment: @NetMage You were right about m being null -  ` m?.MinutesSpent ?? 0 ` takes care of it .  Your SQL to LINQ Recipe is exactly what I am looking for as well !

Answer (score 1):

Under the section "Actual Code" just add a parenthesis in Sum function, as below
It should take care of null , even before Sum works.

```
select grouped.Sum(m => (m.MinutesSpent ?? 0)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do for you, using LINQ - Lambda Expressions:

```
var TotalMinutesSpentGroupedList = timelabels
         .GroupJoin(challengedetails,
                    t => date,
                    cd => createddate,
                    (t,cd) => new 
                    { 
                       MinutesSpent = cd.minutesspent ?? 0,
                       CreateDate = cd.createddate ?? DateTime.Now
                    })
         .SelectMany(tcd=> challengedetails.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                     (t, cd) => new 
                     { 
                        MinutesSpent = cd.minutesspent ?? 0,
                        CreateDate = cd.createddate ?? DateTime.Now
                     })
         .Select(s => new 
                     { 
                        MinutesSpent = cd.minutesspent ?? 0,
                        CreateDate = cd.createddate ?? DateTime.Now
                     })
         .GroupBy(g => g.createddate).Select(item => item.Sum(s => s.minutesspent));
```